# Rails unique tags for each User with has_many_through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to make tagging system with User specific tags, so each user should have access to tags created only by this User.

Relations are:

```
Package
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings

Tag
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :packages, through: :taggings

Tagging
  belongs_to :package
  belongs_to :tag
```

What relations should be with `User`?

```
Tag
  belongs_to :user

User
  has_many :tags
```

Or:

```
Tagging
  belongs_to :user

User
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
```

Or:

```
Tagging
  belongs_to :user

User
  has_many :taggings
```

Comment: do you want `many to many` relationship or `has many` ?

Comment: @GaganGupta User should have many tags, but each Tag should has only 1 User

Comment: then you don't have to use `has_many_through`